# error too many re-renders. react limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

It seems that calling the todoList which is mapped to state is causing the issue, but I don't know why...how do I get the array of todos in my state to display in the table without this error?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getTodos } from '../../actions/todo';

//Bootstrap Table
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';
import paginationFactory from 'react-bootstrap-table2-paginator';
import * as ReactBootStrap from 'react-bootstrap';

const UserTable = ({ getTodos, todoList }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getTodos();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const columns = [
    { dataField: 'id', text: 'ID' },
    { dataField: 'userId', text: "User's ID" },
    { dataField: 'title', text: 'Title of Todo' },
    { dataField: 'completed', text: 'Is this done?' },
  ];

  setTodos(todoList);

  return (
    <BootstrapTable
      keyField='id'
      data={todos}
      columns={columns}
      pagination={paginationFactory()}
    />
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  todoList: state.todo.todoList,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getTodos })(UserTable);
```

Comment: This is causing it `setTodos(todoList);`. Use it at initialization with `const [todos, setTodos] = useState(todoList);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider avoiding setting the state directly inside function body - it will cause an endless loop.

Anyways - why do you want to keep it inside state? I would suggest you to operate on the props.

```
return (
  <BootstrapTable
    keyField='id'
    data={todoList} // todos directly from props
    columns={columns}
    pagination={paginationFactory()}
  />
);
```

Comment: This worked for me and I removed the the const [todo, setTodos] = useState([]) and I can now see the data.